# htaccess 301 redirect before rewrite and remove query string

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I've got two rewrite conditions based on what a user enters. The first is for a company we have listed, the second is for those that we don't have listed.

```
RewriteRule ^companies/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/index.php?action=companies&param=$1&articleId=$2 [NC,L,B]
RewriteRule ^companies/([^/]+)/$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/index.php?action=companies&param=$1&articleId=0 [NC,L,B]
```

I've found some common misspellings e.g. 'm&s' rather than 'marks & spencer' so I want to 301 redirect the user straight there e.g.

301 redirect from: http://www.example.com/companies/m&s/ to http://www.example.com/companies/marks-\&-spencers/557/

I've used this in the htaccess in various locations:

```
redirectMatch 301 ^/companies/m&s/$ http://www.example.com/companies/marks-\&-spencers/557/
```

However the resulting URL is http://www.example.com/companies/marks-&-spencers/557/?action=companies&param=aldie&articleId=0

How do get it to display without the query string so it's just http://www.example.com/companies/marks-&-spencers/557/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your version of Apache is >= 2.4, you can use the flag [QSD] to avoid rewrite the query string :

```
RewriteRule ^companies/m&s/$ http://www.example.com/companies/marks-\&-spencers/557/ [R=301,QSD]
```

If it's an older version of Apache, you can use a little trick, add an interrogation mark at the end of the rewritten URL, to have an empty query string :

```
RewriteRule ^companies/m&s/$ http://www.example.com/companies/marks-\&-spencers/557/? [R=301]
```